# Trying to read tweets in R stored in a csv file

Tags: r, csv, twitter

I have some tweets stored in a csv file on my local computer.There are 1248 rows. Now when I try to read these tweets in R using the read.csv function I get 1816 rows. This is happening because there are some tweets which have commas in them so basically what read.csv does is it splits one tweet into multiple tweets based on the number of commas and hence more number of rows. So what separator should I define to read the file correctly?

Thanks

Comment: Try to put quotes around text fields when building csv

Comment: So you are creating this file yourself? Try using `tab` as a delimiter instead maybe. But there's not really anything you can guarantee that won't be in a tweet. CSV files can contain commas in values if properly escaped or delimited. Maybe use a proper CSV file writer to create the file.

Comment: Show the data. Otherwise it's guess work.

Comment: The fields with embedded commas should be delimited with double-quote by default. I tried to replicate a file with CSV with embedded text and commas, I do not have any issue reading the CSV file into R. May be, you can try open the CSV file save it as an excel file?

Answer (score 0):

Use read.table or read.delim instead of read.csv and use the quote parameter. There's a thread on this that will provide all the details
[[read.table with comma separated values and also commas inside each element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19400282/read-table-with-comma-separated-values-and-also-commas-inside-each-element][1]).

Answer (score 0):

convert csv file to xlsx and use the following code:

library(readxl)
dataset <- read_excel('C:/Study/..._Sample1.xlsx')